# ObjectiveC - constructor, memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory

I'm beginner ObectiveC user so please keep potential answers simple.
I have quite a few years experience with C and C++.

Now, with ObjectiveC I want to create two objects, not using properties. My question is "what is wrong here" not "how to do it differently".
So there is my code:

```
@implementation News

NSString *_title;
NSString *_excerpt;
NSString *_content;
NSString *_thumbnailURL;
NSString *_date;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title excerpt:(NSString *)excerpt content:(NSString*)content thumbnail:(NSString *)thumbnailURL date:(NSString *)date {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:title];
        _excerpt = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:excerpt];
        _content = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:content];
        _thumbnailURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:thumbnailURL];
        _date = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:date];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)showData {
    NSLog(@"    title:%@", _title);
    NSLog(@"    excerpt:%@", _excerpt);
    NSLog(@"    thumbnailURL:%@", _thumbnailURL);
    NSLog(@"    date:%@",  _date);
    NSLog(@"    getContent:%@", _content);
}
@end
```

Now I want to create two objects:

```
News *nws = [[News alloc] initWithTitle:@"title1" excerpt:@"excerpt1" content:@"content1" thumbnail:@"thumbnail1" date:@"date1"];
News *nws2 = [[News alloc] initWithTitle:@"title3" excerpt:@"excerpt3" content:@"content3" thumbnail:@"thumbnail3" date:@"date3"];
```

After that want to show whats is inside this objects:

```
[nws showData];
[nws2 showData];
```

Result is that both objects have the same values inside. All ended with "3". I thought that nws object will containt values ending with "1" and nws2 will contain values with "3". But it isnt working like that. Why? Where is an error?
Please help and thanks!

Comment: The problem is you are missing {} around the fields in the @implementation.

Comment: Jano, thx! The reason was missing {} around the fields. THX!

Comment: I'm thinking how this code without {} was interpreted by the compiler. And why compiler didn't show any warnings... I'm not sure if I can understand potential answer (beginner Objective-C) but it's really interesting.

Comment: Type `clang -rewrite-objc News.m` and read the result. The field is just there outside any object struct. And yes, it is a funny case, I'm looking for it on Apple's Objc documentation but can't seem to find a reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked in twitter and got the following comment from @Bavarious:

https://gist.github.com/11c22c0edea5391a3799 (bold added)

> **Any variable declared outside of `@interface … {}` or `@implementation … {}` is treated as a regular C variable**. 
>   In your example, `_excerpt`
>   is a global (file scope) variable with static storage duration and
>   could equivalently be placed at the top of the file before
>   `@interface`, or between `@interface` and `@implementation`, or
>   between the implementation of two methods — it’s the same mechanism
>   where file scope variables in C are defined outside of a function
>   block.
>
> Variables with static storage duration can be used to realise class
>   variables, a concept that doesn’t exist in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are defined as `global variables` (and not instance variables), this why they have the same same value referenced from your instances.

Embedding them in {} is a possible solution in your case.

Comment: Sorry, it's not class variable. It's global variable just like Jano said. More about "class variables" in Obj-C: http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/class-variable-for-objective-c-and-c/